# i386-pc-mingw32-objdump pe disassembling aborted

Tags: linux, disassembly, mingw32, binutils

I am trying to disassemble Sid Meiers Railroads 1.1 original binary from 1C disc

```
file RailRoads.exe
>>PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
sudo crossdev i386-pc-mingw32
i386-pc-mingw32-objdump -D RailRoads.exe > RailRoads.dump
>>Aborted
i386-pc-mingw32-objdump -v
>>GNU objdump (GNU Binutils) 2.22
```

How to deal with such problem? Do you know other disassembler (working on linux) that can work with pe-i386?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to download the evaluation version of [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml). MinGW objdump isn't really meant for much more than disassembling binaries generated by MinGW tools.